# Почему в слайдере Swiper не работает кнопка вызова модального окна FancyBox?

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка, swiper

Есть слайдер Swiper:  http://05314.sergeykonovalenko.com.ua. Внутри слайдов находится кнопка "Get Started", которая вызывает модальное окно FancyBox.

При переключении слайдов часто возникают случаи, когда при клике на кнопку "Get Started" не происходит открытие модального окна, оно может открыться только после нескольких кликов по кнопке. Также бывает, что при переключении слайдов, после клика по кнопке происходит смена слайда, а не вызов модального окна.

Чем может быть вызвано подобное поведение, как это исправить?

На странице ничего лишнего нет, только оригинальный слайдер Swiper и FancyBox.

Comment: Скорее всего проблема в том, что во время клика вы слегка двигаете мышкой, и тогда уже не считается кликом и Swiper блокирует событие нажатия. Попробуйте при нажатии на кнопку использовать `stopPropagation`. И да, весь код должен быть в вопросе, а не на стороннем сайте.

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте в каком порядке инициализированы `swiper` и `fancybox`. Столкнулся с этой проблемой, удалось решить инициализацией `fancybox` **ПОСЛЕ** инициализации `swiper`.